# how do I set the space between paragraphs with beamer?

Tags: beamer, spacing, paragraphs

I am trying to set the space between paragraphs in beamer (in a block environment).

I tried using `\setlength{\parskip}{8pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}` in the beginning of the document, with varying numbers (up to 30pt), but that never changed a thing.

Is there a way to set larger spaces between paragraphs when using beamer?
I could use `\vspace` perhaps (did not try), but that sounds like a bad solution.

EDIT:
I should have mentioned: I am doing it with beamerposter.sty.

here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=230,height=110,scale=1.9]{beamerposter}

\setlength{\parskip}{35pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
  \begin{block}{Title}
  A

  B

  \end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A and B should be much more separated, but they are not here.

Comment: Changing `\parskip` works for me, affecting block environments as well. Perhaps post a minimal working example where it doesn't work.

Comment: it seems like I put the parskip setlength command inside the begin{column} command, then the parskip works (though then the header has a blank line in a block which is not needed), but it works only for that block. Isn't there a way to apply it for the whole document as well as avoiding the unnecessary blank line? minimal working example is hard to get because i am using all kind of nonstandard style files...

Comment: Make a copy and reduce step by step - either you'll get a tiny example or isolate the cause to be in one of those steps. For me, `\parskip` works globally in the preamble.

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but the `times` package is obsolete. See the [`psnfss2e`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf) documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using `\addtobeamertemplate` you can set `\parskip` for each block environment:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parskip}{35pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}}
```

It works with your minimal example.

That command `\addtobeamertemplate` is very useful for many kinds of modifications.

Comment: This solution almost works for me. It works if I enclose my text inside `\begin{block}` environment. However, if I put paragraphs directly inside the `\begin{frame}`, it doesn't work. And yeah, I've tried using `{frame begin}` in your code, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, well... Just setting `\parskip` like the sample code in the question works for me.

Comment: @Denilson Sá: fine :-)