# Beamer: set global parskip for all columns

Tags: beamer

It seems that `parskip` does not affect columns which was also discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6111/how-do-i-set-the-space-between-paragraphs-with-beamer). However, Stefan's solution seems to work only in block environments (which I do not want to add everywhere). So I thought that I try to patch the column environment with `etoolbox`. In this regard, I tried to add the following commands to the preamble without effect:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
%\BeforeBeginEnvironment{column}{\setlength{\parskip}{2cm}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{column}{\setlength{\parskip}{2cm}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        foo

        bar
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{\textwidth}
                foo

                bar
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{\textwidth}\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
            foo

            bar
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Is there any way to set a parskip in every column to make it work like in the last frame of the MWE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the command to the `columns` environment does not work, as beamer does not insert the text directly into the columns, but first creates `minipages` into which the text goes. But you can add the `\parskip` to the minipages:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@minipagerestore}{\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        foo

        bar
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{\textwidth}
                foo

                bar
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{\textwidth}\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
            foo

            bar
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]